# Extract words before a specific pattern

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column with different names in the rows:

```
hello_world_xt_x_D3_m6
bye_bye_x_D1_m3
h1_man_xt_x_D3_m6
bonjour_no_x_D1_m12
```

I would like to remove the ending part which follows the pattern

```
_x_DN_mZ
```

where N is a number between 0 and 3 and Z is a number between 0 and 16.

I would like to have

```
hello_world_xt
bye_bye
h1_man_xt
bonjour_no
```

I think I should use a combination of search and trim/right, but I do not know how to apply it.

I have tried with `=substitute(a2, "_x_D2_m3","")` but I do not know how to extend it regardless the numbers which follows D and m

Comment: Will the numbers following `D` and `m` only be `[0-3]` and `[0-16]`, or might there be other numbers following which you do NOT want to remove.  eg `D4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Wildcards (See the ? in the search string)

EDIT: replace second ? with *

Formula: `=LEFT(A2,SEARCH("_x_D?_m*",A2)-1)`

[image]

Comment: If `_D` stands for Day it could also be 2 numbers. Then `=IFERROR(LEFT(A2,SEARCH("_x_D?_m",A2)-1),LEFT(A2,SEARCH("_x_D??_m",A2)-1)` would be a nice option.

Comment: It would still not work if the D has 2 numbers (but the example data doesn't show it either, so maybe I'm overdoing it). I introduced an IFERROR to search for a match with 2 digits after D.

Comment: OP said Z has two digits. Not N

Answer (score 3):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=MID(A1,1,FIND("_x_",A1)-1)
```

and copy downward:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Would this do?
`=LEFT(A2,FIND("_x_",A2)-1)`